# How to refresh a form?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a userform with a button on it. I want the button to "refresh" the form, in other words I want the form to end, and then reopen.

The code below won't work because the form/macro has already ended, but I want the button to perform this task or similar.

```
sub command1.click()
end
userform1.show
end sub
```

I have checked and tried most or all the options I can choose from for a userform to "refresh". Is this even possible?

Comment: You can do `UserForm1.Repaint`

Comment: is there also another way besides repaint?

Comment: `Me.Hide` then `Me.Show` ? idk what is the whole point of **refreshing** it? Define *refreshing* and elaborate why you're doing it like that. It sounds like a bad design choice to me

Comment: I agree with @mehow. Even using .Repaint is not ideal as repainting is automated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very simple way. Simply Re-Initialze the Userform using the `UserForm_Initialize`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.Text = "" '<~~ Just an Example

    '
    '~~> Put here the code to re-initialize the userform which will refresh it
    '
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBox1.Text = "Sid"

    MsgBox "Re-Initialzing the Userform"

    UserForm_Initialize
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code Panda but can you add a small description to let people know what it does or why you think this should solve the problem. Thanks.